# Python: what to fix in the following code to make it run?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code where i am facing error and i am unable to identify the actual issue here. The code takes a .json file which holds the words and their meanings and finds the exact or nearest matches of the words given as input by the user along with their meanings. The code was running fine until i tried to modify it a little. I wanted to add the matching words where the first word is capital in the following line post which it started throwing exception:

### Changed line:

```
if (word != "") and ((word in data.keys()) or (word.capitalize() in data.keys())):
```

### Code:

```
import json
import difflib

def searchWord(word):
    if (word != "") and ((word in data.keys()) or (word.capitalize() in data.keys())):
        return data[word] 
    else:
        closematch = difflib.get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]
        confirmation = (input(f"\nDid you mean: {closematch} (y/n): ")).lower()
        if confirmation == 'y':
            return data[closematch]
        else:
            return 'Word Not Found in Dictionary'


print('Loading Data...\n')
data = json.load(open('data.json'))
print('Data Loaded!\n')

word = (input('Enter word to lookup in dictionary: ')).lower()

meanings = searchWord(word)
if meanings == list:
    for meaning in meanings:
        print("\n"+meaning)
else:
    print(meanings[0])
```

### Error:

```
Loading Data...

Data Loaded!

Enter word to lookup in dictionary: delhi
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\Learning\Python\AdvancedPython\PythonMegaCourse\DictionaryApp\dictionary.py in <module>()
     20 word = (input('Enter word to lookup in dictionary: ')).lower()
     21 
---> 22 meanings = searchWord(word)
     23 if meanings == list:
     24     for meaning in meanings:

E:\Learning\Python\AdvancedPython\PythonMegaCourse\DictionaryApp\dictionary.py in searchWord(word)
      4 def searchWord(word):
      5     if (word != "") and ((word in data.keys()) or (word.capitalize() in data.keys())):
----> 6         return data[word]
      7     else:
      8         closematch = difflib.get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]

KeyError: 'delhi'
```

The .json file has got a key named Delhi however, the `capitalize()` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to access the word from the dictionary, you are not capitalizing it.

This is not a clean way to handle it but to give you the idea.

```
if (word != "") and (word in data.keys()):
    return data[word] 
if (word != "") and (word.capitalize() in data.keys()):
    return data[word.capitalize()]
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to bang my head for a long time but failed to notice this one simple thing :)